# OpenGL: Drawing lines

Tags: opengl, drawing, line

If I want to draw lines, pure lines with GL_LINES primitive with only two positions.

Should I turn ON the glPolygonMode to GL_LINE too ? Or set the drawing primitive to GL_LINES is enough ?

EDIT: I use modern OpenGL technics

Comment: If you have just 2 points then I recommend to use the `GL_LINES` [primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive). For any triangle primitive you would need at least 3 vertices (points).

Comment: Yes I know that, I wanted to know If I should change the glPolygonMode() state too.

Comment: The polygon mode doesn't affect line and point primitives. It just changes the rasterization of polygons (triangles) - see [`glPolygonMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPolygonMode.xhtml)

Comment: Ok thank you ! I got some troubles to have my lines on screen, I can discard this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is useless and superfluous to change the polygon mode, when rendering line primitives.
As the name suggests, polygon mode only affects polygons ([triangle](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives) primitives), but it doesn't affect [line](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Line_primitives) and [point](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Point_primitives) primitives. [`glPolygonMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPolygonMode.xhtml) just controls the rasterization of polygons (triangles).

Comment: Yes, as well as culling mode. Thank you for the refresh, I was unsure because I never draw lines directly. (My bug was the VBO...)